# How to avoid the default Access Error using Forn_onError event?

Tags: vba, ms-access

On using the code below, my custom message pops up. But after that Default Message of ACCESS also shows up despite my response statement. No idea what I am doing wrong here.

My code:

```
Private Sub Form_OnError....
   If DataErr = 3162 then
      MsgBox"ABC"
      Response = acDataErrContinue
   End if
End sub
```

Comment: Please provide your *actual* code, copied from the code window.

Comment: Actually, I tried copying code, but I couldn't paste that in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access is a bit inconsistent in how to cancel event.

To cancel these kinds of error messages, use `DoCmd.CancelEvent`.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
   If DataErr = 3162 then
      MsgBox"ABC"
      DoCmd.CancelEvent
   End if
End sub
```